# How can i custom config CHANGELOG.md using standard-version npm package?

Tags: npm, configuration, package, version

I'm using the command `standard-version` each time I want to publish new version, but the yielded changes in the `CHANGELOG.md` look like this:

```
### [10.1.9](https://github.com/my-project-name/compare/v10.1.8...v10.1.9) (2021-03-29)

### [10.1.8](https://github.com/my-project-name/compare/v10.1.7...v10.1.8) (2021-03-29)

### [10.1.7](https://github.com/my-project-name/compare/v10.1.6...v10.1.7) (2021-03-29)
```

first the links do not work - the github url is not correct and i want to configure it to the right url, and second, I'd like to configure the link that's shown in the changeslog file (there are some types)

I tried to use this documentation but didn't find anything that can help me
https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog

so how do I configure the way `standard-version` works on the `CHANGELOG.md` ? can someone provide example?

Answer (score 1):

yes.

according to doc:

> You can configure standard-version either by:
>
> 1. Placing a standard-version stanza in your package.json (assuming your project is JavaScript).
> 2. Creating a .versionrc, .versionrc.json or .versionrc.js.
>
> If you are using a .versionrc.js your default export must be a configuration object, or a function returning a configuration object.
>
> Any of the command line parameters accepted by standard-version can instead be provided via configuration.
>
> Please refer to the conventional-changelog-config-spec for details on available configuration options.

example:
.versionrc

```
{
  "types": [
    {
      "type": "feat",
      "section": "Features"
    },
    {
      "type": "fix",
      "section": "Bug Fixes"
    },
    {
      "type": "chore",
      "hidden": true
    },
    {
      "type": "docs",
      "hidden": true
    },
    {
      "type": "style",
      "hidden": true
    },
    {
      "type": "refactor",
      "section": "Refactor"
    },
    {
      "type": "perf",
      "section": "Performance"
    },
    {
      "type": "test",
      "hidden": true
    }
  ]
}
```